# How to print top five highest numbers from a column?

Tags: awk, perl, sort

I have a text file with four columns. I need to read till end of file and print the highest number from column3 (top 5 values) along with column 1.

**input.txt**

```
xm|340034177|ref|RT_235820.1|   139697  192 0
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1|   153819  2607    0
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|    153821  1937    0
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1|   161452  1688    0
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|    150568  105 0
```

**output.txt**

```
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1|   2607
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|    1937
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1|   1688
xm|340034177|ref|RT_235820.1|   192
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|    105
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort -k3n,3 filename | tail -5 | cut -d " " -f1,6-7
```

The above command will sort the file on the 3rd field. Now, I am piping this output to the `tail` command to print the top 5 numbers in the 3rd column. However, if you need only the first column and this 3rd column in the output, you can pipe the output to `cut` command.

**Testing**

```
cat filename

T_235820.1|   139697  192 0
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1|   153819  2607    0
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|    153821  1937    0
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1|   161452  1688    0
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|    150568  105 0
T_235820.1|   139697  192 0
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1|   153819  607    0
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|    153821  937    0
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1|   161452  1881    0
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|    150568  1051 0
```

Now, I run the above command on this file.

```
sort -k3n,3 filename | tail -5 | cut -d " " -f1,6-7
```

The output that I get is,

```
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|  1051
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1| 1688 
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1| 1881 
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|  1937
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1| 2607
```

**EDIT**

You can add the -g flag for floating point and negative numbers as well in case if you have any in your file. The command would look like,

```
sort -k3ng,3 filename | tail -5 | cut -d " " -f1,6-7
```

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the file before process it with `awk`:

```
$ sort -rnk3 file | awk 'FNR < 6 {print $1,$3}' OFS="\t"
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1|   2607
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|    1937
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1|   1688
xm|340034177|ref|RT_235820.1|   192
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|    105
```

Or you can use `perl` alone to do the job:

```
$ perl -anle '
    push @a, [$F[0],$F[2]];
    END {
        $" = "\t";
        print "@$_" for (sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } @a)[0..4];
    }
' file
xm|161622288|ref|RT_340093.1|   2607
xm|75755638|ref|RT_557407.1|    1937
xm|108773031|ref|RT_678101.1|   1688
xm|340034177|ref|RT_235820.1|   192
xm|30352011|ref|RT_784766.1|    105
```